# how to get user User Token on c#

Tags: c#, facebook

I want to get the list of friends of an user (that Confirmed my app on the past, but I no more have his user accessToken

```
var fb= new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get("me/friends/");
```

how do I get his accessToken by `soicalId` and my `appId`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an FQL query mentioning socialId and AppId.

You can build an FQL query here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

To run FQL query try this.

string query = "Your Query";
var result = (Json)fb.Get("FQL", new { q = query });

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i still, Do not understand how it can help me I no more have his accessToken